# run an action in pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis

I wish to apply my action on pyqgis (in a plugin).

In my QGIS plugin, I created an action that I apply to a certain layer. The action appears well on my layer but it is not automatically applied, I have to do it manually.

I think I should use the run() function of the QgsAction class.

```
layer_hypothese = iface.activeLayer()
action_layer_hypothese = layer_hypothese.actions()
actionDescription = 'Graph radar '
actionCode = 'from qgis.utils import iface; iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Feature ID: [% $id %]", 0)'
scope = {'Feature','Layer','Canvas','Field'}


action_graphique = QgsAction(QgsAction.GenericPython,actionDescription,actionCode,'',False,'',scope)
action_layer_hypothese.addAction(action_graphique)
```

Comment: You can run with selectedFeatures using `doActionFeature` but if you want call this action when canvas is clicked need capture this event overwriting `canvasReleaseEvent` and create a custon function for select feature inside this click etc